# How to get a table row to extend to 100% width when child cells do not span the full width of the table (Picture included)

Tags: html, css, sass

The only solution I have found is to fill in the table with empty table cells (Shown in `ROW1` and `ROW7`)

`ROW3` through `ROW6` contain only a single table cell which does not span the full table width. I've tried a fixed layout table and everything I can think of on the table-row to get it to fill in to 100% width without luck.

The reason I need the row to be full width is so that I can show top and bottom borders on the row, spanning the full width of the table.

I'm working on updating software for a client and must use tables and must find a solution that is compatible in Internet Explorer 10 minimum.

All table related elements use their natural display types, `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell`

The rows are generated programmatically and colspan is a problematic solution.

Thank you for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply a border on table rows, but you *can* apply an outline:

```
tr {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Example 1:**

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0; 
  empty-cells: show;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you pointed out in the comments, an outline surrounds the entire element.

To have a single border at the bottom of the row, put it on a pseudo-element:

```
table {
  position: relative;             /* pseudo-element will be based on the table's position */
  overflow: hidden;               /* don't let the pseudo-element overflow the table */
}

tr:before {
  content: '';                    /* required for rendering */
  position: absolute;             /* absolute positioned */
  width: 100%;                    /* span the entire table */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* the magic border */
}
```

**Example 2:**

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0; 
  empty-cells: show;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table {
  position: relative;               /* the pseudo-element will be based on the table */
  overflow: hidden;                 /* don't let the pseudo-element overflow */
}

tr:before {
  content: '';                      /* required for rendering */
  position: absolute;               /* absolute positioned */
  width: 100%;                      /* span the entire table */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;   /* the magic border */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Row3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is very clever. Is there anything to your knowledge that I can do to have only a 1px outline where two table rows meet instead of 2px? I know you can't apply outline to only one side and to my knowledge you can't move table rows with `position: relative` or `margin-top: -1px;`

Comment: This is extremely elegant. I think if you are not using a fixed width table you might have some trouble with this as 100% width was interpreted as the width of the page and not the table, leading the borders to extend over the rest of the page, but since the software I'm working on is ancient, it is a fixed width and I'm in business after changing width to be 2px shorter than the width of the table. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't know the problem was just the border. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Maxwell.  Your `colspan` answer would usually solve a problem like this.  Note that you can use `colspan="9999"` to avoid hard-coding a span that may vary in a dynamic table.  (Assuming the table has no more than 9999 columns.)

Answer (score 2):

Apply colspan on the cell:

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5">oi</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
  <td>oi</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I updated my original post just a minute or two ago to mention colspan is not an ideal solution due to programmatic generation and some other considerations, though it is usable if there's no other way. I did see that mentioned elsewhere but forgot to mention. Any other methods available?

Comment: Can't you detect if the Row will be filled before render it? if not, maybe you can user grids instead of tables.

Comment: Definitely doable but there are other user interface concerns that arise from the cell itself being 100% width as opposed to only the row. I have a handful of non-ideal solutions and was hoping to find what would be a better way to do this as I'm likely to encounter this issue in a number of places during this project.

Comment: You can use divs and grids instead of tables too. This way, you can detect with css the element existance and control width, but you may loose table features like auto width of cells

Comment: But maybe, you should check your project, because ignoring this problem (no control of content) can lead to an future problem.

Comment: Not something in my control